# django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: python, django, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect the remote oracle database. I have installed clients and added the path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

The query and parameters generated are as follows. The query runs in `psql`, `dbeaver`. It only fails when running Django.

```
SELECT "AUTHTOKEN_TOKEN"."KEY", "AUTHTOKEN_TOKEN"."USER_ID", "AUTHTOKEN_TOKEN"."CREATED",  
"AUTH_USER"."ID", "AUTH_USER"."PASSWORD", "AUTH_USER"."LAST_LOGIN", "AUTH_USER"."IS_SUPERUSER",  
"AUTH_USER"."USERNAME", "AUTH_USER"."FIRST_NAME", "AUTH_USER"."LAST_NAME", "AUTH_USER"."EMAIL",  
"AUTH_USER"."IS_STAFF", "AUTH_USER"."IS_ACTIVE", "AUTH_USER"."DATE_JOINED" FROM "AUTHTOKEN_TOKEN" INNER  
 JOIN "AUTH_USER" ON ("AUTHTOKEN_TOKEN"."USER_ID" = "AUTH_USER"."ID") WHERE "AUTHTOKEN_TOKEN"."KEY" =  
:arg0 FETCH FIRST 21 ROWS ONLY   

{':arg0': <django.db.backends.oracle.base.OracleParam object at 0x10b8497d0>}
```

and the error I am seeing is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 497, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 414, in initial
    self.perform_authentication(request)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 324, in perform_authentication
    request.user
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 227, in user
    self._authenticate()
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 380, in _authenticate
    user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/authentication.py", line 196, in authenticate
    return self.authenticate_credentials(token)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/authentication.py", line 201, in authenticate_credentials
    token = model.objects.select_related('user').get(key=key)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 425, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 269, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/kishorpawar/.virtualenvs/pl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/base.py", line 535, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Can you please help me find what could be wrong here?

**UPDATE 1:**
Oracle version is `Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`

**UPDATE 2:**
I installed instant client libraries of version `11_2` and added them to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I am still facing the issue

Comment: Update your question with the DB version

Comment: @ChristopherJones the remote database version is `Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FETCH FIRST 21 ROWS ONLY` syntax was new in Oracle DB 12.1.

I suggest you upgrade your DB e.g to XE 18c https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html

Comment: Or downgrading a `cx_oracle` to `5.2.1` should work too, right?

Comment: Or I need to downgrade `Django` :-(

Comment: What could be the repercussions of upgrading 11g to 18c? Or how could I figure that out?

Comment: You can ask the DB people, e.g. at https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/oracle_database_express_edition_xe